# Password space: number of possible password combination

Tags: passwords

How do I calculate the password space of a randomized linked hybrid pasword of 9 images and 10 numbers(0-9)? User allowed to select 4 password

Images=9
Pin= 0-9
Password selection allowed: 4
Every image is linked to a number

Images are randomized at each selection

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to calculate the password space for a graphical password of 9images each image is linked to a number from 0-9.. and users are allowed to select just 4 images

Comment: The answer is 9-choose-4 I think.

Comment: @GloriaJiya So you want to know the keyspace when you have 10 images (images numbered 0 through 9 would total 10 images, not 9) to choose from, and four are picked at random. Is that correct?

Comment: @forest yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that a password is composed of images is irrelevant. If you have 10 possible values for each symbol and choose 4 symbols at random, the keyspace is 10<sup>4</sup> = 10000, and log<sub>2</sub>(10000) ≈ 13.3 bits.

This is **very** insecure!

---

In general, you can calculate the keyspace by raising the number of possible symbols to the number of randomly-selected symbols. This tells you how many possible combinations there are. You convert this number into the number of bits of security by taking the base-2 logarithm of the result.

For example, if you are choosing a password composed of 12 words chosen at random from a set of 4000, the number of bits of security is log<sub>2</sub>(4000<sup>12</sup>) ≈ 145 bits, which is secure.

Comment: Ok, for hybrid password password that has a password space for 1st step authentication of 10,000 and 2nd step authentication of 6,000. Do we add 10,000 to 6,000 or multiply 10,000 by 6,000.

Comment: @GloriaJiya Will the attacker know if they got the first password correct before they try the second?

Comment: aforest yes the attacker will know.

Comment: @GloriaJiya In that case, treat it like two separate passwords. First one is broken and _then_ the other, so you aren't adding very much security by using two.

Comment: Okay thank you for the response.